# Add wildcard entries to the KDE proxy settings?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, proxy

I have Googled this but cannot find it. I am currently using Kubuntu 11.10 64-bit. I am trying to set up an exceptions list for my proxy using the KDE control panel but when I try use common wildcard symbols, I get the error message:

```
Make sure none of the addresses or URLs you specified contain invalid or 
wildcard characters such as spaces, asterisks (*), or question marks(?).
```

Does there exist a wildcard that can be used here? If not, what is the easiest way of setting up my exceptions list?

Answer (score 1):

You can only set exceptions for a specific host or a specific subdomain. If you want to exclude all hosts under the `example.com` domain, specify `.example.com` as an exception.

If you were trying to write `*.example.com`, then `.example.com` is what you meant. If you were trying to write `a??.example.com` to exclude `a12.example.com` and `a47.example.com` but not `a1.example.com` or `b42.example.com`, you'll have to list all the items explicitly, or use a [PAC file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config#The_PAC_file).